# É possivel baixar a página do link exibido no input com onclick?

Tags: html, script

Esta é a div com o input que exibe o link!

```
<div>
<input type="text" class="mb-5 form-control" id="linkIn" readonly>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="copiar()">Copiar</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="baixar()">Baixar</button>
</div>
```

Este o script

```
<script>

$("#obterLinkdaLista").on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(".select-users").empty();
});

function obterListaUsuarios(id) {
    $('#idLista').val(id);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controles/obter-lista-usuarios.php",
        data: {id: id},
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data) {
            var $select = $('<select/>', {
                'class':"selectpicker",
                'title':"Usuário...",
                'name': "idUsuario"
            });
            for (j=0; j < data.length; j++) {
                $select.append('<option value=' + data[j].id_usuario + '>' + data[j].nome_usuario +     '</option>');
            }
            $select.appendTo('.select-users').selectpicker('refresh');
        }
    });
    $('#obterLinkdaLista').modal();
}

function listaGlobal() {
    $('#cadastro').modal('hide');
    $('#cadastroGlobal').modal();
}

function removerConfirma(id,nome) {
    $('#remover-conteudo').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><strong> Remover </strong>' + nome + '?</div><button onclick="remover(' + id + ')" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger float-right">Remover</button>');
    $('#remover').modal();
}

function editarGlobalConfirma(id,nome, lista) {
    $('#idGE').val(id);
    $('#nomeGE').val(nome);
    $('#nomeGE').val(nome);
    $('#categoriaGE').val(lista);
    $('#categoriaGE').selectpicker('render');
    $('#editarGlobal').modal();
}

function remover(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controles/remover-lista.php",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function(data) {
          location.reload();
        }
    });
}

$( "#cadastro-form-global" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controles/adicionar-lista-global.php",
        data: $("#cadastro-form-global").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
          location.reload();
        },
        error: function(data) {
          resultado(data.responseText);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

$( "#editar-form-global" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controles/editar-lista-global.php",
        data: $("#editar-form-global").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function(data) {
          resultado(data.responseText);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

$( "#formObterLinkdaLista" ).submit(function( event ) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "controles/obter-link-lista.php",
        data: $("#formObterLinkdaLista").serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            $('#linkIn').val(data);
            $('#obterLinkdaLista').modal('hide');
            $('#linkLista').modal();
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});

function copiar() {
    $('#linkIn').select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}

</script>
```

A função

```
function copiar() {
    $('#linkIn').select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

É a responsável por copiar o link do input, a dúvida seria a forma correta de adicionar o botão para baixar o que está no link que o input mostra.

Answer (score 0):

Como demonstra [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36874826/12114971), você pode utilizar uma função que adiciona o link, com a URL que contém o arquivo para ser baixado, no corpo da sua página, e depois clica nesse link programaticamente.

Ou, você pode utilizar o [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html).

Comment: O link não é estatico, ele muda cada vez que se acessa a página onde está o input, tenho o botão que faz a copia do link mostrado para que eu abra no navegador, e baixe a página. mas queria remover estes passos de copiar e colar, adicionando um botão de download.

Comment: Fiz este mudança no botão Baixar, agora está abrindo em uma nova guia, tem uma forma de baixar está página sem abrir em nova guia?

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="javascript: window.open(document.getElementById('linkIn').value);">Baixar</button>